# wrong # args: should be "::oo::class create App ?definitionScript?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm string to put a TK gui inside of a TCL ::os::class.  I keep getting this error:

```bash
$ tclsh
% puts "$tcl_version"
8.6
% exit

$ tclsh stuff2.tcl
wrong # args: should be "::oo::class create App ?definitionScript?"
    while executing
"::oo::class create App {

    constructor {} {
        set bg "lightgrey"

        set win [toplevel .app]
        wm title $win "GUI"
        wm geom..."
    (file "stuff2.tcl" line 3)
```

Here's my code:

```
package require Tk

::oo::class create App {
    variable counter 0

    constructor {} {
        # ...
    }

    method namer {prefix} {
        my variable counter
        incr counter
        return "${prefix}${counter}"
    }

    constructor {} {
        set bg "lightgrey"

        wm title    . "GUI"
        wm geometry . "300x800"

        set callbacks_frame1 [dict create \
            "Button 1" [list self callback_button1_frame1] \
            "Button 2" [list self callback_button2_frame1] \
            "Button 3" [list self callback_button3_frame1] \
            "Button 4" [list self callback_button4_frame1] \
        ]

        set callbacks_frame2 [dict create \
            "Button 1" [list self callback_button1_frame2] \
            "Button 2" [list self callback_button2_frame2] \
        ]

        # Create 4 frames
        set frame1 [tk::frame .f1 -bg $bg]
        set frame2 [tk::frame .f2 -bg $bg]
        set frame3 [tk::frame .f3 -bg $bg]
        set frame4 [tk::frame .f4 -bg $bg]

        # Place the frames in the grid with weight and sticky settings
        grid $frame1 -row 0 -column 0 -padx 0 -pady 0 -sticky "new"
        grid $frame2 -row 1 -column 0 -padx 0 -pady 0 -sticky "new"
        grid $frame3 -row 2 -column 0 -padx 0 -pady 0 -sticky "nsew"
        grid $frame4 -row 3 -column 0 -padx 0 -pady 0 -sticky "sew"

        # Set row weights for the frames
        grid rowconfigure .    0 -weight 0
        grid rowconfigure .    1 -weight 0
        grid rowconfigure .    2 -weight 1
        grid rowconfigure .    3 -weight 0

        # Set column weights for the frames
        grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1

        # Frame 1: One row of buttons
        set buttons_frame1 {}
        set i 0
        dict for {button_text callback_func} $callbacks_frame1 {
            set button [tk::button $frame1.btn$i -text $button_text -bg $bg -command $callback_func]
            grid $button -row 0 -column $i  -padx 0 -pady 0
            lappend buttons_frame1 $button
            incr i
        }

        # Frame 2: One row with two buttons and one entry
        set buttons_frame2 {}
        set i 0
        dict for {button_text callback_func} $callbacks_frame2 {
            set button [tk::button $frame2.btn$i -text $button_text -bg $bg -command $callback_func]
            grid $button -row 0 -column $i -padx 0 -pady 0
            lappend buttons_frame2 $button
            incr i
        }
        set entry_frame2 [tk::entry $frame2.entry1]
        grid $entry_frame2 -row 0 -column 2 -padx 0 -pady 0 -sticky ew
        grid columnconfigure $frame2 2 -weight 1

        # Frame 3: ListBox and Scrollbar
        set listbox_frame3 [tk::listbox $frame3.listbox]
        grid $listbox_frame3 -row 0 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"

        set scrollbar_frame3 [tk::scrollbar $frame3.sb -orient "vertical" -command [list $listbox_frame3 yview]]
        grid $scrollbar_frame3 -row 0 -column 1 -padx 0 -pady 0 -sticky "ns"
        $listbox_frame3 configure -yscrollcommand [list $scrollbar_frame3 set]

        grid rowconfigure    $frame3 0 -weight 1
        grid columnconfigure $frame3 0 -weight 1
        grid columnconfigure $frame3 1 -weight 0

        # Frame 4: Label
        set label_frame4 [tk::label $frame4.label1 -text "This is a label" -anchor "w"]
        grid $label_frame4 -row 0 -column 0 -padx 0 -pady 0 -sticky "ew"

        grid rowconfigure    $frame4 0 -weight 0
        grid columnconfigure $frame4 0 -weight 1

        # Frame 3 callbacks
        #$listbox_frame3 bind "<<ListboxSelect>>" [list self callback_listbox_frame3]
        set forever 1
        vwait forever
    }

    # Menu Bar callback functions
    method gui_on_menu_open {} {
        puts "File -> Open was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_exit {} {
        puts "File -> Exit was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_export {} {
        puts "List -> Export
        was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_filter {} {
        puts "List -> Filter was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_cleanup {} {
        puts "Selected -> Cleanup was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_template {} {
        puts "Selected -> Template was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_renamer {} {
        puts "Selected -> Renamer was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_view_io {} {
        puts "Selected -> View IO was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_about {} {
        puts "Help -> About was clicked!"
    }

    method gui_on_menu_settings {} {
        puts "Help -> Settings was clicked!"
    }

    # Callback functions for Frame 1 buttons
    method callback_button1_frame1 {} {
        puts "Button 1 in Frame 1 was clicked!"
    }

    method callback_button2_frame1 {} {
        puts "Button 2 in Frame 1 was clicked!"
    }

    method callback_button3_frame1 {} {
        puts "Button 3 in Frame 1 was clicked!"
    }

    method callback_button4_frame1 {} {
        puts "Button 4 in Frame 1 was clicked!"
    }

    # Callback functions for Frame 2 buttons
    method callback_button1_frame2 {} {
        puts "Button 1 in Frame 2 was clicked!"
    }

    method callback_button2_frame2 {} {
        puts "Button 2 in Frame 2 was clicked!"
    }

    # Callback function for Frame 3 Listbox
    method callback_listbox_frame3 {event} {
        set index [$listbox_frame3 curselection]
        set value [$listbox_frame3 get $index]
        puts "The selected item in Frame 3 is: $value"
    }

} #classs

namespace eval my_app_ns {
    if {[info script] eq $argv0} {
        set app [App new]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the "comment" `#class` at the end; it's not actually a comment in that location! Tcl only regards `#` as indicating the start of a comment when it is found while looking for the beginning of a command name word; it is an ordinary punctuation character anywhere else. The result in this case makes `oo::class create` get an extra argument, and that doesn't work.

Replace with `; #class` as that will be a comment.

Note that this is *different to many other languages*. Tcl's parser really works in quite different ways to what you'll be used to from elsewhere, but it mostly pretends to be fairly similar. The exact definition of comments is one of the areas where the real differences show. (No, comments are not commands beginning with `#`. You can make those too easily enough, but they're a bit annoying to use.)

---

The fact that `#` is an ordinary character in non-leading positions is why this code contains *no* comment:

```
proc globalEval script {
    uplevel #0 $script
}
```

(`#0` says to `uplevel` to use the root stack level, the one with absolute index 0, and that's the global namespace.)